# ¿Cómo puedo llenar un combobox mediante un datagridview que se encuentra en otra clase sin utilizar base de datos en C#?

Tags: c#, combobox, datagridview

Necesito llenar un combobox con los parámetros que posee el DataGridView (apellidos, nombre, teléfono) que se encuentra ubicada en una clase diferente, pero al momento de ingresar esa información necesito que se guarde en un combobox de las siguiente manera "Apellido, Nombre, teléfono", es decir separados por comas.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.